# Masonry not working on loading... Elements don't re-align themselves until I resize the window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

Example - http://paulmatheson.net/webdev.html

Resize the window and the elements will move accordingly.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/masonry.pkgd.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.imagesloaded/4.1.2/imagesloaded.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  var $container = jQuery('.masonry-grid');
  $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $container.masonry({
      columnWidth: 225,
      gutter: 10,
      itemSelector: '.dev-grid-item'
    });
    $container.imagesLoaded.done( function() {
      $container.masonry('layout');
    });
  });
</script>
<script src="js/lightbox.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
```

My script - Now I think it has to do with imagesLoaded because the console lends some info. It says imagesLoaded.done is not a function but I never had this issue before redesigning a few elements today. Anyone know why it would pop up now?

Comment: Did you download `imagesLoaded.js`? I don't see it in your HTML

Comment: @JosanIracheta it's a `script` tag in the snippet and on their site

Comment: You can download it here: https://imagesloaded.desandro.com:

Comment: You're calling imagesLoaded wrong. try using this syntax https://codepen.io/mcoker/pen/xrKzbK

Answer (score 1):

Your error is with `$container.imagesLoaded.done`

Try this code:

```
 var $container = jQuery('.masonry-grid');
 $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
 $container.masonry({
  columnWidth: 225,
  gutter: 10,
  itemSelector: '.dev-grid-item'
});
$container.imagesLoaded().done( function( instance ) {
  $container.masonry('layout');
});
});
```